# Why are twistors commuting?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, spin-statistics, twistor

In  [his book](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf), Srednicki introduces the notion of twistor in chapter 50. It is described as a simply commuting spinor, as opposed to anti-commuting. How do we know that this object is simply commuting? Since it carries a spinor index, I expected the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably OP is worried that the [spin-statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem) states that spin $1/2$ fields should be described by Grassmann-odd (as opposed to Grassmann-even) fields. Recall that in the [Dirac field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields), the Grassmann-odd nature sits in the creation and annihilation operators.

On the other hand, the Dirac spinors $u_s({\bf p})$ and $v_s({\bf p})$, which Ref. 1 discusses, are Grassmann-even. In particular the commuting spinor $\phi_a$ that Ref. 1 mentions around eq. (50.8) is a Grassmann-even left-handed  Weyl spinor.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; Chapter 50. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html).